# What to write in startDate and endDate under Event of schema.org, if event is happending all the time?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

There is no start date and end date, but this fields are recommended.

Comment: what does "all the time" mean? Are you monitoring human metabolism? Measuring radiation, seismic activity, wave motion?

Comment: I have language course in school of foreign languages, i want to add single course as an event, course dont have particular start date and end date. Course begin immediately when someone enroll it.

Comment: then it's not an `@Event` it's `@Course` https://schema.org/Course Markup appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for an answer

Answer (score 0):

If your events are infinite, then this is not an event but a process.